Could we control our personal reality
In my story one of my characters suffers from delusions of grandeur that he is or will become God. The reason he believes this is because of how his brain works. This character was born with a NEW mental disorder that constantly keeps his mind in a state similar to a lucid dream. What this means is if he imagines anything in his minds eye, it bleeds over and becomes parts of his personal reality “imagine it kind of like self induced hallucinations”. An example is if he imagines an apple in his minds eye, it will bleed over and be “pasted” into his reality. It’s this mental disorder that makes him grow distant from others and what makes him become the main antagonist.
But as I was writing my story I wondered if the mental disorder my character has is possible. And if it’s possible, then what’s the science behind it?

After reading your Q and Robert's A, I'd like to point something out. "Control" is the wrong word. It implies choice, which implies comprehension of limits. Schizophrenics (which I agree is the closest match) don't control anything. The disorder has their subconscious constructing the personal reality on-the-fly to rationalize the outside world's behavior with their inner conviction. Frankly, we all do this to one degree or another (such as old memories becoming reframed in terms of today's troubles or arrogance, which is just personal godhood by another name) it just isn't debilitating.

We used to call this "imagination". Bloody internet, VR and AI destroying a normal human state!

People significantly out of touch with reality are rarely successful enough to be a threat to others, beyond the threat that a regular institutionalized or homeless person may pose if they get violent.

An hallucinated apple won't feed him tough. If he thinks these delusions are real, how come he doesn't simply starve? Since imagening a pizza is easier than actually buying one.

I can see some problems with this premise. So this character thinks "Wouldn't it be great to have a cold beer right now" and lo and behold, he sees a glass of cold beer right in front of him. But, if he tried to drink it, it wouldn't work, and he'd realise that he's hallucinating. Or if he thought how it would be great to have $1000 in cash, and the pile of money immediately materializes in his hand - he wouldn't be able to buy anything with it, and he'd realise he was having delusions. So his mental problems must run deeper than just the disorder you've described.

@GiantSpaceHamster Hallucinations alone are not enough, but many disorders that cause hallucinations also cause delusions. Delusional disorders allow a person to continue to believe a thing even if it is proven incorrect, such people are quick to come up with outlandish explanations of why any proof to the contrary is either faulty or somehow supports thier belief, and if they can not, they will often simply find such evidence incomprehensible and forget you even said anything within a couple of seconds.

And in some cases they will unconsciously do one thing while they believe they did something else.  So, he may think "Wouldn't it be great to have a cold beer right now", then he could go to the fridge, get a beer, and sit back down, and "WOW, I just made this cold beer appear!" So in this context, a delusional person might believe he is doing miracles, but in truth he's robbing banks and such. So hallucination + dilutions + disassociation could make for a very dangerous bad guy.

What you describe is functionally identical to what they call schizophrenia. You know that thing where, at first glance, you thought something was a spider, but on closer inspection it turns out to be a bit of string? Or the cases where you thought you heard someone say something? That can be their entire life, and closer inspection reinforces the spider impression.
When coupled with depression, it tends to result in the patient building undeniable proof (in their head) that people are out to get them. For the sociopathic, it can convince them that they have the inalienable right to harm others.
I recommend watching The Voices with Ryan Reynolds. It's a decent movie, and it is also a shockingly realistic treatment of an extreme case.
Another good one is Special with Michael Rapaport. In this case, he's given drugs that make him think he has super powers, but it's close enough.

While renaming Schizophrenia was discussed, it was decided to continue to include it as the proper name in current and next generation publications of the DSM.

An important truth about this is that the schizophrenic's delusions incorporate the reality around them as they form their own. In other words, such a person would believe they are God but that belief is built around the fact that they can't part or walk on the waters, etc., meaning there will be explanations as to why those miracles aren't seen by the public. Sadly, I've a friend who suffered this specific condition. Though "cured," he'll tell you that there's a part of him that still believes it to be true - but he's come to grips with not trusting that part of himself.

Delusions of Grandeur
Delusions of Grandeur are the belief that you are a person of extraordinary
importance and/or having abilities that you do not actually possess.  It can be a symptom of a wide range of mental disorders including schizophrenia, bipolar disorder, narcissistic personality disorder, dementia, and delusional disorder.  Most of these disorders come with other harmful or debilitating side-effects that may not work for your story though.  So which disorder you go with will be important for how you want the character to play out.

Schizophrenic Delusions of Grandeur are typically accompanied by crippling paranoia in that you think your importance has made you the target of some dangerous person or organization.  So, if your antagonist believes the good guys are demons sent to take revenge on him and that they pose a credible threat, then Paranoid Schizophrenia would fit well.  That said, Paranoid Schizophrenics are rarely in control of thier hallucinations and delusions.  They are typically triggered by things that are outside of the person's control.

If you want your antagonist to swing between belief that he is God and that he is worthless, then Bipolar may be a better fit. These moments of vulnerability might make him a more pitiable character if you want the audience to feel bad for him.  Manic hallucinations tend to be overly optimistic; so, being able to control, or atleast the belief that you can control you hallucinations would be typical.

If you want the antagonist to see himself not just as God, but everyone else as far beneath him, then Narcissistic Personality Disorder is the right way to go. Narcissistic don't typically hallucinate per say, but thier faith in themselves tends to be great enough that they would not need hallucinations to convince themselves beyond the shadow of a doubt that they are God.  Narcissism in many ways makes for the ideal bad guy because there are no hallucinations to get in the way of thier effectiveness.

Dementia is probably a bad choice since it tends to come with too many reductions in faculties to make for an effective bad guy, but if you want the bad guy to be someone you don't expect that the good guys just can't seem to figure out, thier age and frailty could easily be the thing that helps maintain the mystery.

Lastly, if you just want to keep it simply isolated to delusions, but otherwise he's a normal guy, then Delusional Disorder is its own thing.  He could just be a normal guy who just so happens to believe beyond the shadow of a doubt that he is God.  This is the sort of thing that probably works best if the antagonistis is more of an anti-hero where creating a relatable character is important.


Whatever way you go with it, make sure to research the disorder well.  Poor characterizations of specific mental disorders can very easily come off as bigoted or in poor taste if not handled well.

I don't have any mental disorders (AFAIK), but can pretty easily do what your antagonist does. It simply is a feature of my imagination being very visual (at the cost of somewhat reduced abstract imagination). I can pretty much overlay reality with a "movie" written directly by my conscious imagination, or just replace part of my visual view with imaginary "Augumented Reality" apparitions. With sufficient focus, I can fool not only my visual and audio processing, but imagine smells, pleasure, pain, heat, or proprioception shifts with very high veracity.
The problem is, it takes immense focus, attention, and short term memory to keep the "apparitions" from vanishing within seconds. For example, I can, pretty easily, imagine a dog being there with me in the room. I can imagine how it looks, how it sounds, how its fur smells, and the fur texture. It is as close to a real dog as it could possibly be. But the moment I take my eyes, or focus, off the imaginary dog, all of it vanishes, and I cannot imagine the same dog the same way again. It is as if my brain had only enough RAM to use on a a single short scene, but loses track of whatever is not currently "on".
Therefore, your antagonist would need Photographic/Eidetic Memory atop of his visual imagination, coupled with very high functional IQ to make the "virtual hallucinations" stick.
All of it is entirely possible, and I would argue that plenty of painters, "mad" scientists, and daydreamers have such a combo. None of it would explain why your character is antagonistic though. The simplest reason might be that their "personal reality" pushes them towards narcissistic solipsism.
